# LRU cache design using dict and doubly linked list

Tags: python, linked-list, hash-map, cache

> Design and implement a data structure for Least Recently Used (LRU) cache. It should support the following operations: get and set.
>
> - get(key) - Get the value (will always be positive) of the key if the key exists in the cache, otherwise return -1.
> - set(key, value) - Set or insert the value if the key is not already present. When the cache reached its capacity, it should invalidate the least recently used item before inserting a new item.

This problem can be easily solved by using `collections.OrderedDict`. But I'd like to do the practice by using dict and doubly linked list. Can anyone help me check the following code?

```
class LRUCache:
    # dictionary + doubly linked list
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, key, value):
            self.prev = None
            self.key = key
            self.value = value
            self.next = None

    # @param capacity, an integer
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity, self.dict = capacity, {}
        self.head, self.tail = self.Node('head', 'head'), self.Node('tail', 'tail') # dummy head node and dummy tail node
        self.head.next = self.tail
        self.tail.prev = self.head

    # @return an integer
    def get(self, key):
        if key not in self.dict:
            return -1
        else:
            self.insertNodeAtFirst(self.unlinkNode(self.dict[key]))
            return self.dict[key].value

    # @param key, an integer
    # @param value, an integer
    # @return nothing
    def set(self, key, value):
        if key in self.dict:
            self.insertNodeAtFirst(self.unlinkNode(self.dict[key]))
            self.dict[key].value = value
        else:
            if len(self.dict) >= self.capacity: # remove the least recently used element
                del self.dict[self.unlinkNode(self.tail.prev).key]
            self.dict[key] = self.Node(key, value)
            self.insertNodeAtFirst(self.dict[key])

    def unlinkNode(self, node):
        node.prev.next = node.next
        node.next.prev = node.prev
        node.prev = None
        node.next = None
        return node

    def insertNodeAtFirst(self, node):
        node.prev = self.head
        node.next = self.head.next
        self.head.next.prev = node
        self.head.next = node
```

Answer (score 4):

First off, the way you're commenting your functions is completely wrong. Proper commenting for functions uses [Python docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). For example:

```
def my_func( ... ):
    """
    Write a description of your
    function and it's arguments
    here.
    """
    ...
```

Secondly, according to Python's official style guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), your naming is incorrect. Variables and functions should be in `snake_case`, and classes should be in `PascalCase`. If the variable is a constant, it should be in `UPPERCASE_SNAKE_CASE`.

Finally, why do you have `Node` as a subclass of `LRUCache`? Why can't `Node` be a top-level class? I see no reason it shouldn't be.